# Nginx 500 Internal Server Error [FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:]

Tags: php, nginx

I am unsure why this is occurring. My wordpress site loads fine.

Is it something with my PHP code?

```
<?php 
$urls = array(
        "http://www.mb103.com/#"
        "http://www.mb103.com/#"
        "http://www.mb103.com/#"
        "http://www.mb103.com/#"
        "http://www.mb103.com/#"
        "http://www.mb103.com/#"

        ); 
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)]; 
header("Location: http://$url"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a parse error because you have no `,` between your array entries. Try fixing it like this:

```
<?php 
$urls = array(
        "http://www.mb103.com/#",
        "http://www.mb103.com/#",
        "http://www.mb103.com/#",
        "http://www.mb103.com/#",
        "http://www.mb103.com/#",
        "http://www.mb103.com/#",
        ); 

$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)]; 
header("Location: http://$url"); 
?>
```

In many languages (including php) the `,` after the last entry is optional. Including a `,` after the last entry is a good idea because it is easier to edit the file and harder to forget a `,` while editing.